# Extending JavaScript arrays in V8 and maintaining PACKED kind

Tags: javascript, inheritance, optimization, v8

I've read about [packed arrays in the V8 engine](https://v8.dev/blog/elements-kinds) and would like use them in some performance-critical parts of my game (for example as a container for particles).

I would like to make a custom subclass of Array that will always stay PACKED but it seems it's not possible to extend self with another array.

```
class PackedArray extends Array {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    extend(values) {
        // `values` is another array.
        // This obviously won't work, is there another way?
        this = this.concat(values);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to extend sub-classed array instance and maintain the PACKED kind in V8?

I know I can push values one by one or even call `this.push(...values)`, but it's slower than `.concat()` and fails for large arrays.

Comment: wat is the size of your prospective array you want to push in? I removed my answer, cause I didn't read your last sentence ^_^. Could you possibly give a test scenario, so we have something to work towards?

Comment: @Icepickle From dozens to thousands of elements.

Comment: @Icepickle There are many of scenarios, some examples: list of event receivers for custom signal implementation, list of in-game entities, list of renderable sprites, etc. In a game each array should be as fast as possible because they are accessed and iterated over thousands times per second.

Comment: @Icepickle So I would need a generic container that would allocate memory in chunks (extend itself) and could be used in as many scenarios as possible.

Comment: I'm the author of the V8 article you link to. Creating a `PackedArray` subclass is mixing a V8 implementation detail with your code, which should be avoided IMHO. In general, focus on writing readable, idiomatic code. If you want to avoid holes in your array, there's no need to create a subclass for it -- just use the techniques you already mentioned. Note that even `HOLEY` elements kinds can be optimized, so depending on your use case, the perf difference might not be a big deal. Have you measured the impact of `HOLEY` vs. `PACKED` on your code?

Comment: @MathiasBynens For desktop games I'm using NW.js and Electron, which use V8 internally. I didn't yet measured performance in my use case because I can't implement the PackedArray and it seems I won't be able to complete it at all because there is no way to "extend" it.

Comment: @MathiasBynens I've found a small benchmark that makes this difference between HOLEY and PACKED visible: https://jsperf.com/packed-vs-holey-arrays/28

Comment: I'm well aware it's possible to construct benchmarks that show a difference. I was asking if you saw a difference for the real-world code in your application (as opposed to synthetic microbenchmarks). If the answer is no, then this is premature optimization.

Comment: @MathiasBynens I've a working game which seems simple, but uses 25% CPU on my desktop and 100% CPU time on mobile. So I'm searching for all possible ways to optimize it. I would be able to see if there is a difference in performance if I would be able to implement the "extend" operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

V8 developer here. TL;DR: the best thing you can do with "packed elements" is not to worry about them. The difference is almost never measurable.

In certain microbenchmarks, where there are only a handful of machine instructions in the optimized code for the hot core loop, every single instruction matters, and if the "hole"-check for the current element is one of them (actually two: `cmp` + `je` on x86), then tracking which arrays don't need it can affect the benchmark score. But in real-world applications where you do non-trivial operations on the array element, the impact of two machine instructions is not measurable. Any contortions that you go through with your custom wrapper class are most likely more expensive than the minuscule bit of overhead you might be able to save.

---

The specific question you ask can be solved by preferring "has-a" over "is-a" composition:

```
class PackedArray {
  extend(values) {
    this.#data = this.#data.concat(values);
  }
  get(i) { return this.#data[i]; }

  #data = [];
}
```

Which would also address the issue that with a subclass, code could still use `my_packed_array[10000] = "now you have holes"` to side-step the `.extend()` method. However, keep in mind what I wrote above: the impact of a hole-check is *tiny*, and any of these extra wrappings probably cost way more than they save.

EDIT: what @MathiasBynens writes is also a very good point: Don't optimize for V8, let V8 optimize for you! :-)

Comment: If the difference between HOLEY and PACKED is almost never measurable, then why this two kinds were implemented in V8? Why not just stick with HOLEY in V8 internals and simplify code? Mathias Bynens says explicitly in the article that this distinction exist to increase performance.

Comment: *almost* never measurable captures the motivation ;-) . -- We are updating the article right now to be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this.splice()` to modify the current array.

```
extend(values) {
    this.splice(this.length, 0, ...values);
}
```

Comment: This would still be limited by the number of values that would get added, no? Does it have any advantage over `this.push( ...values )`?

Comment: It might be similar, I'm not sure. I'm not sure why either of them would have a limit.

Comment: Well the limit seems kinda big, but there are some questions available here which say it's around 32766 arguments depending on how you call it